# Protractor tests in Docker - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL

Tags: angular, docker, protractor

I have written 6 e2e tests , using protractor for my Angular2 application. 
The tests run fine  on my windows 10 system . The tests are consistent and pass all the time.

Now I am trying to run the same tests in CentOS  docker container. 
The tests are not consistent. They keep failing .

I get an error saying

**Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.**

I have increased the time out , I have given browser.wait(till presence of ) in required places , I have increased the computing resources allocated to docker ( CPU-3 , Memory-3328MB)  .  nothing seem to have worked.

```
 // Protractor configuration file, see link for more information  

const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
      'args': [ '--no-sandbox']
    }

  },
  directConnect: false,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3200/',
  framework: 'jasmine2',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {
      // NOOP
    }
  },
  beforeLaunch: function() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
  },
  onPrepare() {
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  }
};
```

One of the tests

```
// create a user and he should be able to login after creation
  it('should add a new user and log him in successfully', () => {
    browser.wait(until.presenceOf(userCreate.forename, 5000, 'Timed out'));
    const forename = 'newUserFore' + generateRandom.generateRandom();
    const surename = 'newUserSur' + generateRandom.generateRandom();
    const username = 'newUserUser2' + generateRandom.generateRandom();
    const password = 'Pass@123' + generateRandom.generateRandom();

    userCreate.addUserWithPassword(forename, surename, username, password);
    // select language
    userCreate.selectDropdownByNumber(userCreate.mylang, 1);
    // select role
    userCreate.selectDropdownByNumber(userCreate.myrole, 1);
    // click add
    userCreate.addUserButton.click();
    browser.wait(until.presenceOf(userCreate.successMessage, 5000, 'Timed out'));
    expect(userCreate.successMessage.getText()).toContain('User saved successfully!');
    // cancelbutton
    userCreate.cancelbutton.click();
    browser.wait(until.presenceOf(userOverview.addUserButton, 5000, 'Timed out'));
    // logout
    indexPage = homePage.menu.navigateTo(MenuOption.LOGOUT, until);
    // click on login button on first page
    loginPage = indexPage.loginButtonClickedOnBasePage();
    // login with the credentials
    browser.wait(until.presenceOf(loginPage.loginTitle, 5000, 'Timed out'));
    loginPage.login(username, password);
    browser.wait(until.presenceOf(menu, 5000, 'Timed out'));
    expect(menu.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
  });
```

The functional test file , where I first start the server and then run the ui

```
     #!/usr/bin/env bash
    echo  "API: Ensuring the port $API_SERVER_PORT is freed."
    fuser -k -n tcp $API_SERVER_PORT


    echo " Starting the server in detached mode. This will take about 5 minutes the first time  "
    cd ../api && mvn spring-boot:run  -D server.port=$API_SERVER_PORT >> api-start.log 2>&1 &

    # Wait for the server to come up..
    while ! (ncat -w 1 127.0.0.1 $API_SERVER_PORT </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1); do sleep 1; done
    echo "Server started on port $API_SERVER_PORT"


    echo "UI: Ensuring the port $UI_SERVER_PORT is freed."
    fuser -k -n tcp $UI_SERVER_PORT

    npm start >> ui-start.log 2>&1 &

    while ! (ncat -w 1 127.0.0.1 $UI_SERVER_PORT </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1); do sleep 1; done
    echo "Angular app is running on port $UI_SERVER_PORT , startup logs is in start.log".

    protractor container.protractor.conf.js
```

Comment: seems like a service delay.. when there are async service calls this might happen

Comment: I'm dealing with the same thing, we've got 57 specs right now. The same docker-based test containers pass fine on our development laptops but when they're run on the Jenkins docker nodes, it'll fail around the same spot every time with that timeout issue.

Last week I updated the versions of selenium and the chromedriver we're using, and the tests still failed but they failed later, and for the same reason. (The originally failing spec passed no problem.)

Comment: @anjunatl, if it helps you could try, this way of handling Asynchronous specs.  https://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support.
I tried this. The probability of tests passing in Docker container increased . But again it is not full-proof. Tests did fail 2 out of 35 times.

Comment: @DebanjanaMaitra Did you figure out the solution ? I am facing the exact same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried volume mounting the host's `/dev/shm` to the container?

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#running-the-images

That's apparently a known workaround to stop selenium from crashing with Chrome or Firefox inside Docker. The selenium crash wasn't immediately apparent, it was just expressed through the Jasmine timeout instead.